# Why is this transition not working? (jQuery toggle + css)

Tags: jquery, css

Transitions are gone when toggling class? I wanted to add HTML as well, but stackoverflow kept saying that my question was mostly code and would not let me save, that is why I added codepen link, which is working fine now, I have just edited it.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pdmpNE

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col bg-primary one">
      <h1>some text</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col bg-danger two">
      <h1>hidden text</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.two {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.is-visible {
      display: block;
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
            transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

$('.row').click(function(){
    $(this).children('.two').toggleClass('is-visible');
});
```

Comment: Can you please share your complete code along with your HTML the codepen you linked doesn't look like it has anything to do with the code you have posted here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I pieced together what you were looking for, but please next time format your question with all code. Also, if you're going to add a Codepen, make sure to actually add your CSS and JS if you're going to include some.

What I changed is that I added your .two class to your second div and made your $('.row).click() function once the document is ready.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="col bg-danger two">
  <h1>hidden text</h1>
</div>
```

Here's the JS:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.row').click(function(){
    $(this).children('.two').toggleClass('is-visible');
  });
});
```

[Here's the Codepen displaying the changes.](https://codepen.io/ChaseIngebritson/pen/vWwpbo)

Comment: Whoops! Sorry about that, I've updated the pen. Is this is what you're looking for?

Comment: so looks like display: none and display: block are not transitioned properties.

Comment: Ya, unfortunately the display property is not animatable ([as detailed here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)).

Your best bet if you want to try and animate display would be to transition your element out using the opacity property, then change the display of your class to none using JavaScript. [Here's an example.](https://www.impressivewebs.com/animate-display-block-none/)